# Angular could not find module when using libraries

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-library

I am using angular libraries and have the following structure

```
.
└── MyAngularProject/
    ├── projects/
    │   └── my-project-name-here/
    │       └── src/
    │           ├── modules/
    │           │   ├── module1/
    │           │   │   ├── components1/
    │           │   │   ├── components2/
    │           │   │   ├── components3/
    │           │   │   ├── module1.module.ts
    │           │   │   └── module1-routing.module.ts
    │           │   └── module2/
    │           │       ├── components1/
    │           │       ├── components2/
    │           │       ├── components3/
    │           │       ├── module2.module.ts
    │           │       └── module2-routing.module.ts
    │           ├── my-project.module.ts
    │           ├── my-project-routing.module.ts
    │           └── my-project.component.ts
    ├── src/
    │   ├── app/
    │   │   ├── app.component.html
    │   │   ├── app.module.ts
    │   │   └── app-routing.module.ts
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── environments/
    │   └── pollyfills.ts
    ├── angular.json
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── tsconfig.app.json
```

Now I am using the following command to build the libraries before I run the project

```
ng build --project my-project-name-here  --watch
```

and then I am starting the app with `npm start`.

Now when I run this for the first time, I am seeing an error that says

`ERROR in Could not resolve module ./modules/module1/module1.module relative to dist/my-project-name-here/my-project-name.d.ts`

If I save something there in the project/modules, it will again rebuild and this error will be gone. But now when I try to access a page in the browser using routes, it shows that `Cannot find module './modules/module1/module1.module'`

and the page will be redirected to `localhost:4002`. I am not using the app routes actually and all the routes specified in the project's route and in corresponding routes for modules. This might work at times, but if I stop the build command and run it again, it is again showing the same error. How can I fix this once and for all?

I am using Angular 8 and the project route structure in like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-path',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'list',
        loadChildren: './modules/module1/module1.module#ModuleNameModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Also `npm start` runs the `ng serve` command

Comment: Lazy Load Angular Library: https://angularlicious.medium.com/lazy-load-angular-library-micro-applications-648c947821c3